# Debug Android Ionic Application (Android WebView Debugging) Unbound Breakpoints

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I am having issues with using VScode to debug an Angular Ionic app deployed on a native android device.

I followed the following -Debugging with Visual Studio Code in Android

https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging

My launch.json is as follows

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "https://localhost:4300",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "android-webview",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Android WebView",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/www",
            "trace": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I successfully connected to the ADB as i am able to click refresh on the debugger and the application on the native android does refresh so i know the connection is good.

I put a breakpoint on the app.component.ts and it is showing a grey outlined cirlce. Mousing over shows Unbound Breakpoint.

What am I missing?

My process is I run

ionic cap sync
ionic cap open android

Android studios i choose my device and click debug

Visual Studio Code I select the "Attach to Android Webview" configuration and attach
Select my Device
Select the application name

Answer (score 0):

My advice for Ionic Apps is to debug the typescript side using chrome://inspect (or similar) and to use the browser console as on "ionic serve".

I know this is not exactly what are you looking for but it can to be a valid workaround :D

In my opinion it is also more efficient as it allows you to consult the network calls and the rest...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that

1. You are running the app with the command

`ionic cap run android -l --external`

2. You have started the android webview debug after the webview initiates (shows up on a chrome inspect)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with almost the same problem today and finally got it working. I don't want to debug it in Visual Studio Code, only in the browser, but the prerequisites should be the same. So even I'm late to the game I will share my findings

To be able to debug the angular application, more generally *.ts files, you need the source maps to be present in the client. "Normally" only the minimized files are loaded. Because those files don't match the files you put the break point in, the debugger can't match the line numbers, variable names, ....

To create the source maps you need to add `"sourceMap": true,` somewhere in to the build options in your `angular.json`.
To then get it in your app you have different options, I only tested the first one.

1. Add the `--inline` option to `ionic cap sync` like `ionic cap sync --inline`. (See [capacitor cli docu](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/commands/sync which I found thankfullu through this post in the [ionic forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/failed-to-load-source-maps-via-chromium-devtools/197430/7).
2. I also read about what Ravith B. posted.
3. Create your own inline source map function. This is descriped [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/5177027959319-Debugging-Android-Builds-with-Angular)

I didn't tested 2. and 3. so I just referenced them.

To verify that the source map is actually available

1. Deploy you app on the device
2. open chrome browser on you developer machine (not the device)
3. enter chrome://inspect/devices
4. you should see your device, connect to it (`inspect`)
5. Open the developer tools (F12)
6. In the `Sources` tab you should see the minimized files and also `webpack://`

When you open the `webpack://` you should find the structure similar to you IDE there you can navigate the files and set breakpoints. You should also be able to use your IDE / Visual Studio Code to debug now.